# Python: How do I send a SIGINT signal to program opened with 'xterm -e ...'?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I am trying to use Python to send a SIGINT signal to a process created through `subprocess.Popen`. I need to run test.bash and have it open in a new window, then wait 4 seconds, send SIGINT (the equivalent of using Ctrl-C) so I am using the following code:

```
command = "xterm -e bash test.bash"
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split())

time.sleep(4)
os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

I have "test.bash" set up to trap the SIGINT signal, and run a cleanup command. This works when I run "test.bash" straight from the command line. But when I send it through `xterm -e bash test.bash` in Python it instantly terminates the process entirely and does not handle the SIGINT signal at all.

I've tried some things I've read online about killing the process group, but that's not doing anything either. I tried replacing `os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)` with `process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're sending the signal to the `xterm` process. There's no direct way to get the PID of the `bash` process.

Comment: @Barmar Is there an _indirect_ way to get the PID of the `bash` process?

Comment: You could have `test.bash` write its PID to a file and use that.

Comment: You could look up the `pid` like this https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-by-name-and-find-its-process-id-pid/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the `-hold` option to xterm, i.e. `xterm -hold -e`... to prevent it from closing after the bash script completes since you're using sleep in python rather than the shell.

If you're unable to get the right PID, replacing the second line with this might work:

```
cmd = "pgrep -f 'xterm -e bash test.bash'"
id = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Then use `id` instead of `process.pid`